# TPS of EOS network's transaction processing

Tags: transactions

Will EOS get the declared millions grade TPS when it is lunched? Some of the benchmark test shows current TPS is in thousands. It might be the hardware. But is there any bottleneck in the EOS software?

Answer (score 1):

The initial software will be the single-threaded implementation and not support millions of TPS. Block.one plans to add support for multi-threading later, which should increase transaction throughput significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Dan mentioned on the EOS Telegram channel that the jungle testnet ran 600 TPS. If this is sustained it would give over 5M transactions per day which is 4x what anybody is running in production (http://www.blocktivity.info/).

As mentioned by andybets we can expect more from the EOS ecosystem with multi-threading. Where that hits the wall additional performance can be achieved by side chains / cross chain comms. Guess we just need to see how things evolve once main net launches.